# TDBNavigator background transparency color error

Tags: delphi, c++builder, rad-studio, c++builder-10.3-rio

When I add a TDBNavigator to my project, and mark the option FLAT = TRUE, immediately the background colour of my TDBNavigator changes to black, totally losing its characteristic.

When I run the application, TDBNavigator is as shown in the picture, black.

How to solve this problem?

I am using the c++ builder 10.3.3

[image: TDBNavigator]

Comment: I observed that this happens when tdbnavigator comes after another component in the toolbar. If it is the first component (from left to right), this problem does not happen.

Comment: I checked your problem with C++ Builder 10.4.1 and cannot reproduce. Maybe you should consider upgrading? Note: I created a new VCL C++ project, added a TEdit, added a TDbNavigator, set Flat=TRUE, compiled and ran. Everything looks OK.

Comment: Ok! maybe this is a bug fixed in the new version.

Answer (score 2):

I got an alternative. It seems to me a problem with the transparency of these components.

When I insert a TPanel in the toolbar, the same problem occurs. But in TPanel, I have a ParentBackGround property. When I mark it as false, the background of the TPanel becomes transparent again.

So I used the following alternative.

- 1 - Insert a TPanel into the toolbar
- 2 - Place the ParentBackground TPanel property = false
- 3 - Move TDBNavigator into the TPanel
- 4 - Change the TPanel properties:

  a) BevelEdger = false (all)
  b) Autosize = true
  c) BorderStyle = bsNONE
  d) BevelInner = bsNONE
  e) BevelKInd = bsNONE
  f) BevelOuter = bsNONE
  g) Delete CAPTION from panel
- 5 - Change FLAT property of TDBNavigator to TRUE;

That's how it worked.

Answer (score 1):

With 10.4.1 and clang compile a runtime TDBNavigator icon background is black.
I opened an issue https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-31245

[screenshot TDBNavigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnEts.png)